# Exclude Best Practices From Angular Cypress E2E Test Using Axe

Tags: angular, accessibility, cypress

I'm working in an Angular project that has Cypress E2E Tests set-up. The E2E tests are using cypress-axe to perform an accessibility test.

We've been using the Axe DevTools (Chrome Browser Extension) with the 'Best Practices' turned OFF.

However, the cypress-axe test is using the best practices. Is there a configuration we can add to `checkA11y()` to turn off the best practices?

Here's what my `checkA11y()` looks like now:

```
cy.checkA11y(
   null,
   {
      includedImpacts: ["critical", "serious", "moderate"],
      rules: {
         "color-contrast": { enabled: false }
      }
   } as Options,
   terminalLog
);
```

I want to be able to run the E2E tests and get the same result that I would running the browser extension with 'Best Practices' turned off.

Answer (score 0):

Im also looking in to this I think you might need something similar to what you have but with tags turned off something like this.

```
        runOnly: {
        type: 'tag',
        values: ['wcag2a','wcag2aa', 'cat.*']
    },
     rules: {
         'color-contrast': { enabled: true },
         'valid-lang': { enabled: true }
     },
     tags: {
         'wcag2a': { enabled: true },
         'wcag411': { enabled: true },
         'cat.parsing': { enabled: true },
         'cat.keyboard': { enabled: true },
         'best-practice': { enabled: true }
     },
};
```